# Python Fabric error when executing git archive command

Tags: python, git, fabric

I'm running Fabric on a windows 7 machine, when I type:

```
fab production setup
```

I get the following error:

```
[localhost] run: git archive --format=tar master > 20110221142115.tar

Warning: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'git archi
ve --format=tar master > 20110221142115.tar'
```

the fabric file works fine on my Windows XP machine, but I can't seem to get past this error. I also tried running the "git archive" command from the prompt, it works fine no issues. Any idea why Fabric is puking?

Comment: try to add capture=False. Then you can see the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

If the same script/command works on Windows XP, then did you check if Windows 7 firewall or any `sort-of-protection` is not allowing your connection to go through? Try if the following works on interactive prompt:

```
from fabric.api import local
local('git archive')
```

Comment: @Senthil-Kumaran isn't the "run()" function meant for execution on the remote host and "local()" meant for execution on local machine. I tried to run the following command on the prompt: `local('del filename')` and got the same error as the one above. It seems like Windows 7 isn't allowing me to run commands on the local machine.

Comment: Sorry, I mean local. I shall edit it. Yeah, Just check with Windows 7 Properties which should allow you to run commands. ( If you are running from a Shell, make it to Run as Administrator and try).